# SAP Spartacus - How to show the custom components in Spartacus UI

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I have a custom component to display the images as tile in my UI.

I am getting the response as follows for the created custom component from the backend.

components: "Test1Component Test2Component Test3Component Test4Component Test5Component Test6Component Test7Component Test8Component"
container: "false"
modifiedtime: "2020-09-29T20:52:40.454+05:30"
name: "Tiles Component"
typeCode: "TileCollectionComponent"
uid: "TilesCollectionComponent"
uuid: "eyJpdGVtSWQiOiJUaWxlc0NvbGxlY3Rpb25Db21wb25lbnQiLCJjYXRhbG9nSWQiOiJhbHNheWVyLXNwYUNvbnRlbnRDYXRhbG9nIiwiY2F0YWxvZ1ZlcnNpb24iOiJPbmxpbmUifQ=="

How can I retrieve the data and show it in the UI.

Comment: Have you read on https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/customizing-cms-components ?

Comment: Yes I gone through the link.

I am trying to instantiate the componentData like the following.

constructor(private authService: AuthService,public componentData: CmsComponentData<TileCollectionComponent>,
    private cmsService: CmsService) {}

It is showing TileCollectionComponent is not found.

How can I get the response data which is coming from the CMS in spartacus. Kindly advice.

Answer (score 1):

The component data indicates that this component is a so-called container component. Container components do only response the component UIDs. This is a bit unfortunate, as you'd need to interact with the cms service in Spartacus to resolve the component *types*. before you can start rendering them.

We do have an example in our code base that you can use to render these nested components. You see in https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/blob/532603fbcfcf7c21c3abbf4e342fcda03652b61e/projects/storefrontlib/src/cms-components/content/banner-carousel/banner-carousel.component.ts#L25 that we're taken the component data and `switchMap` this to an array of `CmsComponentData`. (using `cmsService.getComponentData`). Spartacus will merge the different parallel requests in the loop automatically to a single backend for the component data.

You can use the `CmsComponentData` array in an ngFor loop, and leverage the `cxComponentWrapper` to iterate over all the `CmsComponentData` objects. The `cxComponentWrapper` will map to the right component and adds other stuff like smartedit integration.

```html
<ng-container [cxComponentWrapper]="component"></ng-container>
```

Although this is all available, your question make me think to build a more easy solution that does the heavy lifting.